# transform QPainterPath to bmp and get two-dimension array of the fill area

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, qpainter

I'm working on a project where I need to mark some areas on loaded picture.Now I use QPainterPath to keep the trace of pen.I want to add the trace and the closed areas to the picture and save it as BMP file.
How could I implement the function?

What's more, I want to get the area statistics of the closed area.So I come up with the idea that to test every pixel to see if it is in the area.My questions:

1.Is there a function that telling a pixel whether in the area.

2.other method to get the area.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, can't you just use a QPainter on the QImage you have and paint the path?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QPainterPath::contains` function to check if the path contains the point. Note however that `QPainterPath` operates vector graphics and doesn't know anything about the painting device or the pen, so `contains` may not work for lines. It will detect if the point is inside a polygon, a rectangle, etc.

As suggested in the comments, you can create `QImage` with appropriate size, use `QImage::fill` to set default background color, create a `QPainter` using `QImage*` constructor argument and paint the path. You can then save the image to BMP file using `QImage::save`. You can also use `QImage::pixel` function to check value of each pixel and determine the area. Note that you may need to call `QPainter::end` before accessing resulting `QImage` to ensure that changes was already written to it.